# How to Click and Create single vertex on an edge in Blender?

Tags: vertices, edges, topology

I want to be able to click somewhere on an edge and create a vertex at that position, as simply as possible.

In this scenario, we are not talking about loop-cuts and also don't care if we are creating n-gones at this step. I'm basically looking for a on-click edge cut.

I saw it being done in Maya, pretty standard over there I think.

Most use-cases for this would be for quickly and manually trying and fix non-quads in meshes, or just play around and trying to improve the mesh.

Is there a tool built-in in Blender that can do this? Are external tools or plugins available?

A few ways i already know but are either to many steps or not exactly what i need:

- select a vertex hit <kbd>E</kbd> (Extrude) move freely and place vertex.
  Have "snap" (to edge or face) and Auto merge / split turned on.
- select a vertex on that edge, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>G</kbd> (this duplicated that vertex and G makes it slide)
- Knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>), but here u always have to cut 2 edges (so basically to split a full shape)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Right Click</kbd> is a fast way to add vertexes at the click position  (but they are not bound to an edge and are also hard to place at they wanted position )
- weird one: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (loopcut) works on some edges of triangles (I don't really understand this on tbh)

Comment: You can also select an edge, right-click and Subdivide it then slide the vertex that's produced, but you have to change from edge to vertex mode before selecting and sliding it.

Comment: as you say there's no way except the ones you cite, Alt D is probably the fastest?

Comment: The Alt-D G (as opposed to GG) is a new one on me! I never realized it would lock to the edge in the drag-direction. Very handy.

Comment: Found another way to create vertices easily (also added to list in original post).
Select a vertex hit E (Extrude) move freely and place vertex. Have "snap" (to edge or face) and Auto merge / split turned on.